# PHP Display 2 xml Nodes Same Time

Tags: php, xml

I would like to display 2 items on differnt nodes at the same time.  Here's my xml file:

```
<applications>
        <application name="CAFC">
                <infos>
                        <info>Apple</info>
                        <info>Banana</info>
                        <info>Orange</info>
                        <info>Pear</info>
                </infos>
                <getstates>
                        <getstate>111</getstate>
                        <getstate>222</getstate>
                        <getstate>333</getstate>
                <getstate>444</getstate>
                </getstates>
        </application>
</applications>
```

Here's my php code.  It works great but it can only display 1 element in the node at a time.  I was thinking of wrapping the second loop it in a for loop but I don't know how to go about doing it.

```
$applications = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($applications as $application) {
        getXML($application, "info");
}


function getXML($application, $info){
    $infos = $info . "s";


    foreach($application->$infos->$info as $info){
        echo $info <br>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I would like to be able to output "Apple 111", "Banana 222", "Orange 333", etc.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the two lists of elements as arrays and simply loop for the count of the first list (assuming they are the same size) and pick the element from both lists...

```
$applications = simplexml_load_file($file);

for ( $i = 0; $i < $applications->application->infos->info->count(); $i++ ) {
    $value1 = (string)$applications->application->infos->info[$i];
    $value2 = (string)$applications->application->getstates->getstate[$i];
    echo $value1." ".$value2.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which with your test data gives...

```
Apple 111
Banana 222
Orange 333
Pear 444
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you